# Ionic Cordova application not working on android 9 devices

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting a problem to run my ionic cordova app on android 9 its working fine on android version less than 9
Application is not hitting the backend in android 9
this is my environment

I tried on samung and onePlus devices bot on android verion 9 and less than 9

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
 Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.6
 @Ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
 Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
 NodeJS            : v8.10.0 (/usr/bin/node)
 npm               : 6.9.0
 OS                : Linux 4.15

Environment:

ANDROID_HOME : /home/aviral/Android/Sdk

Comment: Did you try to set targetSDK to 29?

Comment: did you check your logcat for errors?

Comment: okay i got it fixed. doing
 cordova remove platform android
 cordova add platform android@8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Add network_security_config.xml in platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml. The file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
 <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
 <trust-anchors>
  <certificates src="system" />
  </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Add the above file in  AndroidManifest.xml like

```
 <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
  android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
  android:supportsRtl="true">
```